# how to make the variable take place

Tags: bash, variables, sh, zsh

I have this code in shell script

```
id='this'
sql="hello $id"
echo "$sql"
id="salut"
echo "$sql"
```

it will echo

> hello this
>
> hello this

how can I get

> hello this
>
> hello salut

in other words how can I make the variable id take place when changed inside other variables ?

Comment: `bash` and `zsh` are two different shells; which one are you actually using?

Comment: This smells like SQL injection. Have a look at http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use **eval** but it can be risky (depending on what can be inside your variable).

```
id='this'
sql="hello \$id"
eval "echo $sql"
id='salut'
eval "echo $sql"
```

A good and safe way to do that is to use a function to reset your *sql* variable.

```
prepare_sql() {
    sql="hello $id"
}

id='this'
prepare_sql
echo $sql
id='salut'
prepare_sql
echo $sql
```

You can even put the assignment in the function.

```
change_id() {
    id=$1
    sql="hello $id"
}

change_id this
echo $sql
change_id salut
echo $sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of variables is set at the moment you reference them.  So for what you want, you have to do:

```
id='this'
sql="hello $id"     # here, $id == this, so sql == "hello this"
echo "$sql"
id="salut"
sql="hello $id"     # here, $id == salut, so sql == "hello salut"
echo "$sql"
```

Variables are not re-evaluated when you change them, unless you expressly ask for it.